# What's the bottleneck for java.nio non-blocking I/O?

Tags: java, nio

I know there are many open source server programs that leverage java.nio's non-blocking I/O, such as Mina. Many implementations use multiple selectors and multi-threading to handle selected events. It seems like a perfect design.

Is it? What is the bottleneck for an NIO-based server? It seems like there wouldn't be any?

Is there any need to control the number of connections? How would one do so?

Comment: define `performance` that means about as much out of context as `faster` or `better` ...

Answer (score 3):

With traditional blocking I/O, each connection must be handled by one or more dedicated threads. As the number of connections grows so does the number of required threads. This model works reasonably well with connection numbers into the hundreds or low thousands, but it doesn't scale well past that.

Multiplexing and non-blocking I/O invert the model, allowing one thread to service many different connections. It does so by **selecting** the active connections and only performing I/O when it's guaranteed the sockets are ready.

This is a much more scalable solution because now you're not having hordes of mostly-inactive threads sitting around twiddling their thumbs. Instead you have one or a few very active threads shuttling between all of the sockets. So what's the bottleneck here?

- An NIO-based server is still limited by its CPU. As the number of sockets and the amount of I/O each does grows the CPU will be more and more busy.
- The multiplexing threads need to service the sockets as quickly as possible. They can only work with one at a time. If the server isn't careful, there might be too much work going on in these threads. When that happens it can take some careful, perhaps difficult programming to move the work off-thread.
- If the incoming data can't be processed immediately, it may be prudent to copy it off to a separate memory buffer so it's not sitting in the operating system's queue. That copying takes both time and additional memory.
- Programs can't have an infinite number of file descriptors / kernel handles open. Every socket has associated read and write buffers in the OS, so you'll eventually run into the operating system's limits.
- Obviously, you're still limited by your hardware and network infrastructure. A server is limited by its NIC, by the bandwidth and latency of other network hops, etc.

This is a very generic answer. To really answer this question you need to examine the particular server program in question. Every program is different. There may be bottlenecks in any particular program that aren't Java NIO's "fault", so to speak.

Comment: many thanks to you, and is there need to control connections' number?if no control, maybe oom or other issues occur at last. how to control it?

Comment: If the incoming data can't be processed immediately it would make more sense to just stop OP_READ on that connection, leave the data in the operating system's buffer, don't waste any more memory on it, and let the sender stall.

Comment: @EJP In the case of partial messages, you may not know whether you can process the data without reading it first. I've been dealing with this just this week rewriting my SSL code to be non-blocking. If there's data available I don't know if I've got a complete SSL packet until I've read the buffered data and fed it to the SSL engine. It may consume the data, or it may refuse it.

Comment: @JohnKugelman In that case you just leave it in the `SSLEngine`'s application receiver buffer. It will have told you `BUFFER_UNDERFLOW`, and if there is no more data currently available on the channel you just have to select until there is. There's no point in adding *another* buffer into this.

Comment: @EJP The application buffer *is* the secondary buffer I'm talking about. And it's a buffer I have to maintain. `SSLEngine` doesn't have any buffers of its own.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the bottleneck for an NIO-based server?

The network, memory, CPU, all the usual things.

> It seems like there wouldn't be any?

Why?

> Is there any need to control the number of connections?

Not really.

> How would one do so?

Count them in and out, and deregister `OP_ACCEPT` while you're at the maximum.

Comment: thanks for your answer, What's more, I can't found any practices to control numbers of connections. So is there need to do this? if not control it, the cpu/memory may got out of control?

Comment: take mina as one example. how to control numbers of connections?

Comment: I've answered both those questions. In fact I've answered *all* your questions. What part of my answer didn't you understand?

Comment: your answer is too short and I expected common practice to control number of connections? I am'not sure your practice is common used. 3ks all the same, forgive my English is pool

Comment: My answer is as long as necessary and addresses all your concerns. It isn't clear to me that you're more of an expert on 'common practice' than I am, or why counting things to see when you get to a limit isn't common practice, or how ceasing to do something when you get to that limit could possibly not be common practice either.